# signing safe transactions without using the sdk safeSDK.signTransaction(txs)

Tags: safe-core, safe-core-sdk

Can you point me to do a signTransaction using ethers.js or similar and without the sdk? Would love to do it in dart language. Was able to createTransaction and executeTransaction. Signing is the most complex part.

```
txs = await safeSDK.createTransaction({transactions})
àwait safeSDK.signTransaction(txs)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have detailed explanations of how to sign transactions using Safe Protocol Kit [here](https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit/guides/signatures/transactions), but we don't recommend re-implementing these schemes from scratch, as they are complex and present a security issue if wrongly implemented.

If you are curious you can look at how the protocol kit manages [EIP-712](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/6bb692d64ab0bba4c1d40706e1458ad0ab0a6d2b/packages/protocol-kit/src/utils/eip-712/index.ts) typed data and [signs transactions](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/6bb692d64ab0bba4c1d40706e1458ad0ab0a6d2b/packages/protocol-kit/src/Safe.ts#L663), but, again, at your own risks.

Hope it helps; Best, Louis